# how to get recent 6 dates (Max dates)

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

## I need recent 6 dates count

My code is

```
select DUE_DATE, count(*)
from DATA
group by DUE_DATE
```

```
03/24/2018    10
03/17/2018    20
03/10/2018    15
03/03/2018    23
02/24/2018    42
02/17/2018    32
02/10/2018    15
02/03/2018    17
01/27/2018    23
```

Comment: You may change your query like this:
select top(6) DUE_DATE, count(*) from DATA group by DUE_DATE order by DUE_DATE desc

Answer (score 1):

```
select DUE_DATE, count(*) from DATA group by DUE_DATE order by DUE_DATE desc limit 6
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The simplest case would be if every date is presented and/or you're only interested in 6 most recent dates regardless of whether they're presented in your table or not:

   ```
   select DUE_DATE, count(*)
     from DATA
    where DUE_DATE >= trunc(sysdate) - 5
    group by DUE_DATE
    order by DUE_DATE desc
   ```

   (Note: dates that are not presented in your table won't be shown).

---

2. On the other hand, if you need 6 most recent dates from the subgroup of dates you have in your table, then you'll first need a subquery to fetch you those dates and than use count on those dates only:

   ```
   select DUE_DATE, count(*)
     from DATA
    where DUE_DATE in (select distinct DUE_DATE
                         from DATA
                        order by DUE_DATE desc limit 6)
    group by DUE_DATE
   ```

---

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `fetch first`?

```
select DUE_DATE, count(*)
from DATA
group by DUE_DATE
order by DUE_DATE desc
fetch first 6 rows only;
```